# SQL query for table update

Tags: sql, hibernate

I am quite new to SQL. I have one table with three columns.

```
Person
{
 varchar Name,
 varchar Address,
 int Order
}
```

I am using this table for hibernate mapping. I want to orders to stored in starting from 0. I found NPE issues in my application, for which I found root cause from following thread.
http://www.intertech.com/Blog/hibernate-why-are-there-nulls-in-my-collection/.

**Root cause.**
My Order column doesn't have sequential values. It has values something like this 0,2,5... for Person let's say for John. I want to update this table such that it will have sequential values for Order column for each Person. Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Toss in some data ... that's easiest way to give you some help

Comment: Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: There is a solution for this yes, but looking at data would be easier ... I can write Tsql query for this using row_number function with partition by Name and address ... it's just a lot easier if i can see data